# What parameters are there for exporting only a specific range as pdf through Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that exports a sheet as a PDF although I would only like to export a range within that sheet.

I understand that not all parameters for exporting as PDF are listed on the apps script developers website (I can't find them anywhere!!) so was wondering if anyone knew what the identifiers where for start row and column and end row and column please?

The script it goes into is as below:

```js
 var url="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ss.getId()+"/export?format="+exportType; // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
  + '&size=A4'                           
  + '&portrait=true'                     
  + '&fitw=true' 
  + '&top_margin=2.50'              
  + '&bottom_margin=2.50'          
  + '&left_margin=2.50'             
  + '&right_margin=2.50'  
  + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' 
  + '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' 
  + '&gid='+sh.getSheetId();
```

Comment: You could create a table in Google Docs from the data in a Spreadsheet and create a pdf from that.

Comment: What about the suggestion of @arulselvan of hidding the undesired columns and scripts with your script following [this method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hidecolumnscolumnindex,-numcolumns) of the documentation and then exporting the sheet with Apps Script?

Answer (score 1):

Hide all rows and columns from the sheet (other than the range you want to print).

Export the sheet as PDF.

You are done.